# If I am using two @InitBinder in a one controller then how it belongs to two particular BindingResult?

Tags: spring-mvc

Below code in my controller class.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/library/*")
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("booksValidator")
    private Validator booksValidator;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("loginValidator")
    private Validator loginValidator;

    @InitBinder("login")
    private void initUserBinder(WebDataBinder loginBinder) {
    loginBinder.setValidator(loginValidator);
    }

    @InitBinder("book")
    private void initBooksBinder(WebDataBinder booksBinder) {
    booksBinder.setValidator(booksValidator);
    }

        @RequestMapping(value="welcome", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String printWelcome(@Validated @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult login, ModelMap model) {

        }

        @RequestMapping(value="add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addBooks(@Validated @ModelAttribute("books") Books books, BindingResult book, ModelMap model) {enter code here

        }
}
```

@InitBinder("login") belongs to--> BindingResult login

@InitBinder("book") belongs to--> BindingResult book

How I can do?
Please suggest me...
:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Spring controller can have multiple `@InitBinder` methods. But you are not using correctly the value of the annotation. According to `InitBinder` javadoc about the value parameter, *Specifying model attribute names or request parameter names here restricts the init-binder method to those specific attributes/parameters*

So in your example, you should use `ModelAttribute` names and not `BindingResult` parameter names, that is `@InitBinder("user")` and `@InitBinder("books")` instead of (resp.) `@InitBinder("login")` and `@InitBinder("book")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Serge Ballesta.
:)

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you split this into two separate controllers. One that deals with your users/login and the other to deal with books. So, something like LoginController that has the init binder for login, and BooksController that has the book validator for validating books.

Comment: Isn't Possible to do in single controller?